# Laravel store data from several pages of an API into database

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm calling an API that has 650 records paginated with 20 results per page. I'm wanting to store the returned data into a table in my DB. The issue I face is I'm unsure how to move onto the next page and loop through those results.

Here's my call which gets the first 20 and stores them

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $getData = Http::get('https://example-url.com/Search?House=1&IsCurrentMember=true&skip=0&take=20');
    $jsonResponse = $getData->json();

    foreach ($jsonResponse['items'] as $mp) {

        $mp = new Mp([
            'id' => $mp['value']['id'],
            'name' => $mp['value']['nameDisplayAs'],
            'party' => $mp['value']['latestParty']['name'],
            'constituency' => $mp['value']['latestHouseMembership']['membershipFrom'],
            'county' => '',
            'region' => '',
            'country' => '',
            'active' => $mp['value']['latestHouseMembership']['membershipStatus']['statusIsActive'],
            'image' => $mp['value']['thumbnailUrl']

        ]);

        $mp->save();
    }

    return view('admin.mps.index')->with('success', 'data was successfully add.');
}
```

What's the best approach to do this?

EDIT

Aswell as the results the API returns this

```
"totalResults": 650,
"resultContext": "",
"skip": 0,
"take": 20,
"links": [
{
"rel": "self",
"href": "/Members/Search?skip=0&take=20",
"method": "GET"
},
{
"rel": "page.next",
"href": "/Members/Search?skip=20&take=20",
"method": "GET"
},
{
"rel": "page.previous",
"href": "/Members/Search?skip=0&take=20",
"method": "GET"
}
]
```

I can offset the result by changing the URL parameters `skip=0` just not sure how I would dynamically do this and keep looping through the data.

Comment: I would read the API Documentation for `example-url.com/Search` to see what parameter to change to get the next set. You have obfiscated the real site, so we cannot even loook it up for your

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've updated my question with the additional options. It won't let me put the real API link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from Laracasts here is the solution I've gone with.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $skip = 0;
    $take = 20;

    do {
        $getData = Http::get('https://example-url.com/Search?House=1&IsCurrentMember=true&skip=' . $skip . '&take=' . $take);
        $jsonResponse = $getData->json();

        // save

        $skip += $take;
    } while ($jsonResponse['totalResults'] > $skip);

    return view('admin.mps.index')->with('success', 'data was successfully add.');
}
```